# Read a .cdb file into R very slow

Tags: r

I have .cdb files in binary format in sizes of ~630M.
I use

```
read.cdb(file, type='cdb')
```

from library `cdb` to read them in but it takes for ever to load. (20 min+)
Is this normal for a large file like this?

Comment: This format seems to be quite obscure, and the package has not changed in around 2 years (and is version 0.0.1). I would try and contact the package maintainer and ask feedback.

Comment: I have done that now. Will update if I get answer.

Comment: Hi jasonD, did you get it working ?

Comment: hi Pascal, can you please share the code you used ?